# Can Donkeys and Mules use an Ender Chest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Since Donkeys and Mules can be equipped with a chest and become mobile storage units, can they be equipped with an Ender Chest allowing the player to have a portable connection to a home base Ender Chest? (thus eliminating having to destroy one in order to move it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently, Mojang might add that feature in the future. For now, sadly, we have to destroy them by ourselves... :(